# How to use boost::lambda to create new object for an existing pointer?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread, boost-lambda

What I want to do is --> create a new object in a new thread.
Something like:

```
Class* object = 0;
Arg arg;
boost::thread t( lambda::bind( object = lambda::new_ptr< Class >()( boost::ref( arg ) );
```

it doesn't compile, what's correct way?

Comment: Hint: Use [Boost.Phoenix](http://www.boost.org/libs/phoenix/) rather than Boost.Lambda – the latter has been deprecated for years now.

Comment: If C++11 is an option for you, just do `std::thread t([&] { object = new Class(arg); } );`

Comment: Thanks guys, but I can't use C++11 right now. I'm going to try Phoenix...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ildjarn, I tried with boost::phoenix and got it work, code is:

```
Class* object = 0;
CArg arg0;
Arg arg1;

boost::thread t( boost::phoenix::val( boost::ref( object ) ) = boost::phoenix::new_< Class >( boost::cref( arg0 ), boost::ref( arg1 ) );
```

**Again, from ildjarn, the better code is:**

Class* object = 0;

CArg arg0;

Arg arg1;

namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

boost::thread t( phx::ref( object ) = phx::new_< Class >( phx::cref( arg0 ), phx::ref( arg1 ) );

Comment: This should be `boost::thread t( phx::ref( object ) = phx::new_< Class >( phx::cref( arg0 ), phx::ref( arg1 ) );` (given `namespace phx = boost::phoenix;`). Notably, you should be using `ref`/`cref` from namespace `boost::phoenix` rather than namespace `boost`.